# Vagrant Port Collision on Port 80, but Port 80 is not Forwarded in the VagrantFile

Tags: vagrant, port, virtualbox, collision, forward

I am following a simple tutorial that directs me to install Tomcat with Vagrant:

```
vagrant init emessiha/ubuntu64-java --box-version 1.0.0
```

It then tells me to edit the VagrantFile to forward from 8080 to 8080, then do "vagrant up".  When running "vagrant up" I get this message:

---

```
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 80 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current project's Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

   config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding. You could
try 'vagrant reload' (equivalent of running a halt followed by an up)
so vagrant can attempt to auto-correct this upon booting. Be warned
that any unsaved work might be lost.
```

---

Here is my VagrantFile.  You can see that port 80 is not forwarded.

I tried changing the forwarding ports in VagrantFile from 8080 to 8081, and it did not fix the problem.  I then commented the line.  Still same problem.  I am on a Mac with High Sierra.

---

```
# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "emessiha/ubuntu64-java"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ports are hard coded in the vagrant file

If you look [at the documentation for that vagrant file](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html), it shows that the following ports are already defined

- 3306
- 80
- 8080

I tried to spin up the same vagrant box and found that it used the same ports

```
vagrant init emessiha/ubuntu64-java \
  --box-version 1.0.0
vagrant up
```

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 80 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
```

If you try and redefine which ports the box will use, it appends those ports instead of replacing them.

Here I tried to forward `3306` to `3307`. Instead of replacing the port forward, it added a new entry.

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3307, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

```
    default: 80 (guest) => 80 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3307 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

Since this vagrant box is maintained by someone else, you are at the mercy of the port definitions that they have defined. Either find out what program is already using port 80 and stop it. (`netstat -plnt` on linux) or create your own vagrant box.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer led me to discover that Apache was running on High Sierra by default, unbeknownst to me.