# Vagrant - vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM

Tags: vagrant

When i run `vagrant up` i get the following error:

```
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with another VirtualBox virtual machine's forwarded
ports! The forwarded port to 3306 is already in use on the host
machine.

To fix this, modify your current projects Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.forward_port 80, 1234
```

I checked and i don't have any processes using port `3306` locally.
I also tried `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`, didn't help.
`vagrant suspend` followed by `vagrant resume` didn't help as well.

What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What's your command to find the port?

Maybe you can see this. [Vagrant Port Collision on Port 80, but Port 80 is not Forwarded in the VagrantFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356224/4883754)

Comment: `lsof -i :3306` in my case. Nothing showed up.
I also looked at the question you provided, not sure the answer there helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a process on my machine running on port `3306`.
Running `lsof -i :3306` didn't show it, only when i used `sudo` it did.